# Puppeteer core not executing chromium binary from @sparticuz/chrome-aws-lambda

Tags: puppeteer, chrome-aws-lambda

Trying to run puppeteer-core & @sparticuz/chrome-aws-lambda on a lambda function.

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!\n/tmp/chromium: /tmp/chromium: cannot execute binary file\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: [https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md\n\n](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md%5Cn%5Cn)    at onClose (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:248:20)\n    at Interface. (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:238:68)\n    at Interface.emit (node:events:539:35)\n    at Interface.emit (node:domain:475:12)\n    at Interface.close (node:readline:586:8)\n    at Socket.onend (node:readline:277:10)\n    at Socket.emit (node:events:539:35)\n    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)\n

Comment: any updates? Did you solve the issue?

Comment: i wanna know too.